# How i can delete all data from DB and insert new using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

Now i use only this options

```
ScriptingOptions options = new ScriptingOptions();
options.ScriptSchema = false;
options.ScriptData = true;
options.ScriptForCreateDrop = true;
options.WithDependencies = true;
```

but i get output sript with only

```
INSERT [t].[Table] ([f], [f1], [f2], [f3], [f4], [f5], [f6]) VALUES (N'SomeData', N'SomeData', N'SomeData', N'SomeData', CAST(N'SomeData' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'SomeData' AS DateTime2), NULL)
```

but i want get DELETE ACTION before INSERT

```
DELETE FROM [t].[Table]

INSERT [t].[Table] ([f], [f1]) VALUES (N'SomeData', N'SomeData')
```

How i can do it? Help pls

UPD:
I just use other options and save result into another virable

```
ScriptingOptions optionsForClearData = new ScriptingOptions();
            optionsForClearData.ScriptSchema = false;
            optionsForClearData.ScriptData = true;
            optionsForClearData.ScriptForCreateDrop = true;
            optionsForClearData.ScriptDrops = true;
```

that code give me result StringCollections with values
DELETE FROM [t].[table]
Than i just put it into one big string and save it like .sql rollback file using this part of code

```
            var tt = new StringCollection();
            var s = new List<string>();
            foreach (var tbl in Tables.Reverse())
            {
                s.AddRange(dbs.Tables[tbl].EnumScript(optionsForClearData));
            }
            foreach (var tbl in Tables)
            {
                s.AddRange(dbs.Tables[tbl].EnumScript(options));
            }
            tt.AddRange(s.ToArray());
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);

            var text = new string[tt.Count];
            tt.CopyTo(text, 0);
            tw.Write(string.Join("\n",text));
            tw.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;
            return new FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length, "backup", 
            FileName+".sql");
```

PS: Yes i know about i missed "using" with streams (RAW CODE)

Comment: the SMO is for Manage the server (like make backups), not used for the insert, and delete.

google something like "sql server insert update delete example c#" and follow a tutorial.

Comment: @Aristos i try to made data rollback using this library and when i use Microsoft SQL Managment Studio i can create script what i wanted

Comment: you can use this utility to run an sql script https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a management library for CRUD to a db. You need to be sending validated queries or invoking stored procedures through a data provider

I would recommend [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) which was built by Stack Overflow themselves. Very performant (I believe its only a pinch slower than ADO.NET which is pretty amazing), reduces a lot of ADO.NET boilerplate, and you have as much fine tuned control as you want as you can write your own queries

Alternatively, for a low/no-code option there is also [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). Not as performant, but very feature rich for sure.

If you don't want any external libraries, as I mentioned ADO .NET is a bit more writing but is very fast